# Objective-C: EXC_BAD_ACCESS reading NSData from file path

Tags: objective-c, io

I am trying to read `NSData` from a file path, and eventually unarchive the data.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docs = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[docs stringByAppendingString:@"/dynSplash"]
                          withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                           attributes:nil
                                                error:nil];
NSString *dynamicSplashFile = [docs stringByAppendingString:@"/dynSplash/dynamicSplash.data"];
DynamicSplash *splash;
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dynamicSplashFile]) {
    NSLog(@"Dynamic splash exists");
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dynamicSplashFile];
    splash = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
}
```

The problem arises on the line `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dynamicSplashFile]` where a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error is bring thrown.

How can I debug this?

Comment: how do you define `dynamicSplashFile`? are you using ARC?

Comment: What does the file contain, exactly?

Comment: My first guess would be that the problem is related to `dynamicSplashFile`. Can you show the code where this variable is initialized?

Comment: Add an NSLog of dynamicSplashFile before the dateWithContentsOfFile line.

Comment: Also add an NSLog of "I read the file" after the dataWithContentsOfFile line, since it's not uncommon for line numbering to get confused.

Comment: Edited to show declaration of dynamicSplashFile, and the file contains a serialized copy of a `DyanmicSplash` object using `NSCoding` and `NSKeyedArchiver`